# How is electrostatic potential distributed along a circuit element?

Tags: electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, potential, semiconductor-physics

Suppose we have a diode circuit like that:
[image]

Suppose the voltage has magnitude $\varphi$ and one end of the wire has potential zero.

How will the potential be distributed throughout the diode?

Does $\varphi = \varphi_A = \varphi_B$?

Or will the potential be highest on the red line and then lower as we go up or down due to some electron-hole-ion configurations we have in our semiconductor that may have some effect on electric potential?

How to describe this mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the contact surface, which contains A and B.

If it is metallic, as it is in many (integrated) devices, $\phi = const$ along that surface. Current flow across the diode can be modeled as 1D. (This is also a nice and easy to obtain reference estimate for the next one.)

If A is a point contact and B is practically isolated, then your second description holds. In reality placing a needle on the semiconductors surface by a tester comes close, but can be a mixture with the first case, depending on the dimensions.

See my sketch below:

- AB is high resistive (insulating)
- red is my guess of the electric field inside (not much different than in vaccum)
- pink is the electrical potential, which IS of course perpendicular to the field (as you can see ;)
- the distances of the potential lines roughly indicates distribution of resistance (voltage drops)

A "simple" way to model this is using resistor nets, mimicking the p and n zones. In fact, triangulation is exactly this, done in $2D$-simulators. Instead of triangles ($3$ nodes per triangle) you can also take $4$ nodes, and build such an electric network with an ordinary circuit simulator. (Try it manually, e.g. by dividing both zones into $3*3$ elements and use symmetry between A and O).

Or you can guess stripes of resistors from my sketch (e.g $3-4$ per half from my sketch), put them in parallel, estimate resonable resistances and run your circuit simulator with it.

Or run your $2D$ physical simulator (if you have access to one).

Things like that.

[image]

---

Here's a so called lumped model in a least useful granularity which you can use with a circuit simulator:

[image: lumped model]

Procedure:

- calculate all voltage drops (i.e. potentials)
- map them in $2D$, e.g. on paper
- sketch reasonable curves of constant potential $\phi$
- estimate field lines $\nabla \phi$ as a perpendicular vector field
- increase granularity, i.e. introduce more nodes if needed and repeat.

You can model D either as an ideal diode $I = I_s \times \exp{\frac{V}{v_t}}$ or with a series resistance to take high voltage saturation into account.

Comment: "If it is metallic..." - do you mean metal-semiconductor or metal-metal contact?

Comment: I mean potential difference between points A and B is zero.

Comment: Yeah, but you were talking about metalic contact surface. Do you mean by that "contact of metal with semiconductor"?

Comment: It depends on your process: you can create an ohmic contact as well as a diode characteristic there. You didn‘t state any assumption there. // Take a different route. If you have no access to a physical simulator, circuit simulation is a good bypass. So your world becomes currents and voltages, basically. And your task is representing physics reasonably by ideal components, like a D at the junction, and R_sheet in n- and p-regions outside the junction. And so on.